# Reading Characters from StdIn

Tags: java, char, stdin, calculator

```
    public class New
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Calculator");

            float a = StdIn.readFloat(); 
            char sign = StdIn.readChar();
            float b = StdIn.readFloat();
            float c = 0;

            if (sign == '+')    c = a+b;
            else if (sign == '-')   c = a-b;
            else if (sign == 'x')   c = a*b;
            else if (sign == '/')   c = a/b;

            System.out.println(c);

        }
    }
```

I need some help with this bit of code, I'm attempting to make a calculator that takes StdIn input with both character and float data types.

Comment: You haven't asked a question and it is therefore **unclear what you are asking**.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to ask, I'm getting a runtime error, it is saying unknown input.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Unknown Source)
        at StdIn.readFloat(StdIn.java:142)
        at New.main(New.java:9)

Comment: Can u try the code blow. It uses the scanner. This StdIn seems to be another library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `Scanner` class.

Like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class New
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Calculator");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Parameter ");
    System.out.print("a      : ");
    float a = scanner.nextFloat();

    System.out.print("+|-|*|/: ");
    String op = scanner.next();

    System.out.print("b      : ");
    float b = scanner.nextFloat();
    float c = 0;

    switch (op)
    {
        case "+":
            c = a + b;
            break;

        case "-":
            c = a - b;
            break;

        case "*":
            c = a * b;
            break;

        case "/":
            c = a / b;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Illegal operant");
    }

    System.out.println("Result: " + c);
}
}
```

I added a switch case instead of the else ifs.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting compiler errors involving Scanner class.

Comment: Is the import correct? `import java.util.Scanner;`

Comment: Do I need to download a certain library file for Scanner class to work?

Comment: No, just the correct import at the top. Its there since Java 1.5 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Ahh, that works. Thank you for the help, I'm new to programming and this program has been bugging me for a few days. Now I'm going to fiddle with it, until I know it inside and out.

Comment: NP,  we all started one day. Don't forget to accept

Comment: Ahh nevermind I finally saw the check mark.... Thanks again!